# Reading a large json file char by char

Tags: java, json, jackson

My JSON file size 126MB. it contains only one line [no spaces , so the whole file is considered as single line]. I want to split it into files each 10MB[some random amount].

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED?**

1. I tried to use filereader , streamreader etc . When i use reader.readLine() it throws me a memory error
2. I tried Jackson library.

   ```
   File reader = new File("D:\\registry.txt");
   ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper(); 
   JsonParser jp = new JsonFactory().createJsonParser(reader);
   JsonNode masterJSON = map.readTree(jp);
   System.out.println(masterJSON);
   ```

It also showing the same memory error . How can i do it?

**MY ALTERNATIVE WORST SOLUTION I FOUND SO FAR?**

Convert the file extension to .txt . And started reading char by char until i reach maximum splitting size.Again i have to change the file extension to .json.

Any easiest way to read one line file which is large[more than 100MB] in size??

Comment: Where is `reader` declared? that's kind of weird you're getting a `memory error` with a file that is 126MB, I've loaded `1GB` files without issues. Read [Parsing huge file without reading into memory](http://www.coderanch.com/t/201866/Performance/java/Parsing-huge-file-reading-memory), also mind adding a pastebin for the Error Log(s).

Comment: reader is a file object. I am also wondering why it shows insufficient heap space.

Comment: Use a streaming API like [the one](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/package-summary.html) in [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: @McDowell I was going to suggest Gson too. +1.

Comment: I tried the links. It is showing that gson is not defined at gson.fromJson and error on Message also.[i added gson library also]

Comment: [Using  StreamingJsonBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/index.html?groovy/json/StreamingJsonBuilder.html) to handle JSON streams in groovy (faster than jackson actually).

Comment: I hope so. Thanks , I ll try groovy also.

Comment: You can try Jackson Streaming API (https://www.google.com/search?q=Jackson+streaming+API). When you split one JSON object it will be broken, won't it? Is it acceptable? If yes, you can see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files

Comment: @ludo_rj whether it's faster or not is not guaranteed, despite recent hype based on certain benchmarks -- but regardless, disk read (I/O) will be limiting factor, not parsing.

Comment: @StaxMan my last comment was focused on the serialization process. More infor about [JSON serialization benchmarks](https://github.com/bura/json-benchmarks) comparing GSon, Jackson, Groovy...The next release of groovy 2.3 should be handsome for that.