# Split 30 GB of XML file to small chunks of XML

Tags: java, xml

I have a large dump of Stackoverflow data in XML File.I need to split the file into small chunks of XML files of around 500 MB each.Please provide some suggestions

Comment: My suggestion is to try it first and then come back on SO with more specific problem, not vice-versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files

Comment: I hate it the way some SO people regard questions about design or technology choice as out of scope, and then are happy to criticise when someone makes a poor choice of technology. It's a perfectly good question.

Comment: +1 Michael. The problem is specific enough, and I don't see why we should demand that he try to load it all in memory (won't work) or write his own streamer first (a nontrivial undertaking) before getting suggestions on a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you might be able to use the Unix `split` utility. It won't know about your element boundaries though.

If you need to do this in an XML-aware fashion, here's an article describing another approach, via XML streaming. Coincidentally it describes breaking down a 30 GB XML file:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/splitting-large-xml-files-java

**EDIT**: Michael Kay notes in a comment below (I guess he can't add an answer since the question is closed) that [XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) adds support for streaming, which allows you to process huge files without having everything in memory. Though XSLT 3.0 is at the time I'm writing a draft spec, the [Saxon-EE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) product (which is commercial) supports nearly all of the draft spec.

Comment: The article takes no account of XSLT 3.0, which is designed specifically for this kind of task.