# Split big object before persisting it to file

Tags: java, garbage-collection, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I have an object that occupies approximately 15GB in my java app's heap, and I need to keep it persistent between JVM restarts. I use ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method to write it to file on the disk every time interval. Since the writing process is very long (a few minutes) and causes some GC issues, I would like to split the object somehow to persist each part separately to a different file and not in a single action to a single file. 
Is there a way to do this (and of course to retrieve it back from the files when I need it)?

```
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        GZIPOutputStream gos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("some_path");
            gos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(gos);
            oos.writeObject(myLargeObject);
            oos.flush();
            gos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files) answer. The reverse process of recomposing the split files is nothing more than reading from each individual file and appending to a "master" one.