# Split large files using Java

Tags: java

How can I split a file into parts larger than 2GB?
An array of bytes accepts an int instead of a long as the size. any solution?

```
public void splitFile(SplitFile file) throws IOException {
    int partCounter = 1;
    int sizeOfFiles = (int)value;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];
    File f = file.getFile();
    String fileName = f.getName();

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
            int bytesAmount = 0;
            while ((bytesAmount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                String filePartName = fileName + partCounter + file.config.options.getExtension();
                partCounter++;
                File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), filePartName);
                try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesAmount);

                } 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files

Comment: Do not try to read the *entire file* into a single byte array.  You will devastate your program’s performance.  The whole point of InputStreams and OutputStreams is that you can read and write data a little at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Read file and split into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the entire file into memory, obviously, or even an entire 'part file'.

Your code as pasted will split the file into as many parts as the read method partitions; this seems very silly; after all, the read() method is specced to allow it to partition into single byte increments.

Don't make a new part-file for every call to `read`. Instead, separate this out: Your read call gets anywhere from 1 to <BUFFER_SIZE> bytes, and your part's size is <PART_SIZE> large; these two things do not have to be the same and you shouldn't write the code that way.

Once you have an open `FileOutputStream` you can call `.write(buffer, 0, bytesAmount)` on it any number of times; you can even call `.write(buffer, 0, theSmallerOfBytesLeftToWriteInThisPartAndBytesAmount)` followed by opening up the next part file `FileOutputStream` and calling `.write(buffer, whereWeLeftOff, remainder)` on that one.

Comment: Can you show me an example?